# How do you say “only to find out” in Japanese

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I’m trying to connect two sentences with the phrase “only to find out” / “only to discover”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an uncommon usage of English infinitive (`to + <verb>`) known as [infinitive of result](https://www.grammaring.com/the-infinitive-of-result) (as opposed to infinitive of purpose, which is much more common). To translate "only to ～" into Japanese, you usually have to split the clause into two and join them using が, けれど, etc.

- I did it again, only to fail.
  もう一度やってみました**が**、失敗しただけでした。
- I searched everywhere, only to find nothing.
  あちこち探した**けれど**、結局何も見つからなかった。
  あちこち探した**けれど**、結局何も見つからないという結果になった。
- I went to the bookstore only to discover it was closed.
  本屋に行った**のに**閉まっていた。
  本屋に行った**のに**閉まっていると分かっただけだった。<sub>(more literal but may sound redundant)</sub>